# Can't get babel-loader to add polyfill for String.prototype.trimLeft() (aka trimStart)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I'm bundling my javascript with webpack/babel-loader (with the @babel/preset-env "useBuiltIns: 'usage' " setting), and during compilation the String.prototype.trimStart() polyfill doesn't get added. I tried using its alternate name "trimLeft()," and still no luck. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Node on Mac, I have @babel/polyfill as a project dependency, and I have @babel/core, @babel/preset-env, and babel-loader as devDependencies (as well as webpack). My babel configurations are in my webpack.config.js file.

I'm running babel-loader in debug mode, so I can see which polyfills are being added to which modules; as far as I can tell, it's only trimLeft/trimStart that's a problem. As a result, running my app in IE throws an error.

From package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.29.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
}
```

From webpack.config.js (within module.exports.module.rules):

```
use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                debug: true,
                targets: {
                    browsers: ['IE >= 10']
                }
            }]
        ]
    }
}
```

From the module where I use String.prototype.trimLeft() (within a default export arrow function):

```
const messageInput = document.querySelector('#message-input');
const usernameInput = document.querySelector('#username-input');

messageInput.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
usernameInput.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);

function handleKeydown(event) {
    if (event.key === 'enter') {
        const username = usernameInput.value.trim();
        const text = messageInput.value.trimLeft();

        // etc.
    }
}
```

In browsers that support trimLeft() / trimStart(), this code works fine. I'll add that when I experimented with changing babel settings to target a browser that doesn't support trim(), the trim() polyfill was imported into this module during compilation.

Comment: sounds like the polyfill only sniff for a missing "".trim. you can just alias whatever missing methods are causing the problem; it shouldn't have anything to do with a bundler.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the response. I'm a noob and don't quite know what you mean by "alias whatever missing methods are causing the problem". Also, after snooping around the core-js folder in node_modules, I can confirm that there appear to be trimLeft / trimStart and trimRight / trimEnd "stuff" in various es7 and string folders. So it sure _looks_ like there should be support here.

Comment: something like `if(!"".trimStart && "".trimLeft) String.prototype.trimStart = "".trimLeft;` to alias the missing with the present

Comment: @dandavis To be clear, the problem is browsers that don't support either trimStart() or trimLeft() (like IE 10). And I tried both in my code -- the polyfill doesn't get added regardless of which I use.